# How to take some column from three table in mysql

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

i have three table like:

table 1:

```
|A|B|C|D|
```

table 2:

```
|A|E|F|G|
```

table 3:

```
|G|H|
```

what i need in result is:

```
|A|B|C|D|H|
```

initially i check only the first two table taking, from `table1` all the rows and from `table2` the column `G` in that rows that satisfy the condition `table1.A = table2.A`

something like:

```
SELECT `table1`.*,`table2`.`G` FROM `table1` INNER JOIN `table2` WHERE `table1`.`A`=`table2`.`A`
```

My problem now is to take column `H` from `table3` using like key value `G` that satisfy old condition. i hope my question is a little bit clear.. can someone help me? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `table1`.*,`table2`.`G`,`table3`.`H`
FROM `table1` 
INNER JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.`A`=`table2`.`A`
INNER JOIN `table3` ON `table2`.`G`=`table3`.`G`
```

Comment: as the fieldname is same in both tables, you can use ``USIGNG (`A`)`` insted of ``ON `table1`.`A`=`table2`.`A` ``

Answer (score 0):

This is the most simple way to do it with implicit inner joins.

```
SELECT T1.A, T1.B, T1.C, T1.D, T3.H 
FROM `table1` T1, `table2` T2, `table3` T3 
WHERE T1.A = T2.A AND T2.G = T3.G
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  `t1`.*,
  `t2`.`G`,
  `t3`.`H`
FROM
  `table1` AS `t1`
INNER JOIN
  `table2` AS `t2`
  ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`t1_id`
INNER JOIN
  `table3` AS `t3`
  ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`t2_id` (or join with table 2 I dont know)
WHERE
  `t1`.`A`=`t2`.`A`
```

Answer (score 0):

select table1.A,table1.B,table1.C,table1.D,table3.H  from table1,table2,table3 where  table1.A=table2.A AND table2.G=table3.G